# send predefined data to browser local storage with .crx

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-database

I am building my first chrome extension, for that I want to have some predefined data at client browser.

I want that data be able to be edited by user by means of extension and save back the changes.

I first thought of using HTML5 `local database` or `Indexed Database API`for this.(Am I doing right?)

But I don't know how can I send this local database to client place in `.crx`..because the database will be with browser rather than extension.

How can I send data to client side browser by .crx and save the data on browser?
(I know its not right to save data on browser, but I can't save data back if I save data along with extension)

What other way I can use to implement the requirement?

can I use the same method if I want to use `Indexed Database API` instead?

---

My data is not simple key value pair but table kind of data.
I don't have any code for data access part, because I want to be sure before I can proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can't send database file with ctx file. Simply You can't replace it on client side.
Actually you have two options:

1) save predefined data into your extension (in any extension file. save whole query or data as JSON) and after first run exec those query to local Database.

2) create web service from where you will get predefined data and save it to local DB.

For example (data.json):

```
[{"name":"name", "desc":"desc","some_column":"some value"},{"name":"name", "desc":"desc","some_column":"some value"}, ...]
```

In background.html:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('data.json'), false);
var dataStr = xhr.send(); //don't do this way. use asynch api :)
var data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
//connect to local database
for(var _item in data){
    //create query to insert data into DB
    //and exequte query
}
```

Comment: can you please identify how Offline Dictionary (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mplnjjdpheipggojikpifkibnoaakkii) is implemented?

Comment: Their extension size is about 8 MB and contains definitions data in binary files. It doesn't use local DB or local storage. It use local file system and binary search to load results.